# How can I reach database as json value when i request on my local browser?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

**Note**: This is a project which has a connection with database on other tables. I just made a **new table**, *but i must have something wrong in my codes, because i cant get what i want.*
I have a `City` table, and this table `has 3 columns`, named `id`, name, `city_id`. And i imported a csv file, so when i query, I can see some data.

I wrote `Entity`, `Repository`, `Controller`, and `Service`, in `Java` on Eclipse

What should I do? For example, when i search like `localhost:8181/mfc/city/getAllCities` that should give me all the cities as json

Could you tell me what i should add?

City.java

```
package com.mfc.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="city")
public class City{
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    
    @Column(name="city_name")
    String cityName;
    
    @Column(name="city_id")
    int cityId;
    
    public City() {
        super();
    }
    
    public City(int id, String cityName, int cityId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }
    
    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
    
    public int getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }
    
    public void setCityId(int cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }
}
```

CityController.java

```
package com.mfc.admin.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mfc.admin.service.CityService;
import com.mfc.entity.City;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/city")
public class CityController {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CityController.class);

    @Autowired
    CityService cityService;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllCities", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List getCities() {
        logger.trace("CityController: getAllCities begins");
        List listOfCities = cityService.getAllCities();
        
        logger.trace("CityController: getAllCities ends");
        return listOfCities;
    }
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/getCity/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public City getCityById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return cityService.getCity(id);
    }
    
}
```

CityService.java

```
package com.mfc.admin.service;    

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.mfc.entity.City;
import com.mfc.repository.CityRepository;

@Service("cityService")
public class CityService {
    
    @Autowired
    CityRepository cityDTO;
    
    @Transactional
    public List getAllCities() {
        return cityDTO.getAllCities();
    }
    
    @Transactional
    public City getCity(int id) {
        return cityDTO.getCity(id); // getCity is red here, there is mistake i guess
    }
    
}
```

CityRepository.java

```
package com.mfc.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.mfc.entity.City;

public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Integer>{

    List getAllCities();
    City getCity();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `CityService` you call the `CityRepository` like this

`return cityDTO.getCity(id); // getCity is red here, there is mistake i guess`

But no such method is defined in the `CityRepository`. Try using this line `return cityDTO.findById(id).get();`

You can't see the method `findById(Integer id)` in the `CityRepository`, but it is there, because the `CityRepository` extends `JpaRepository<City, Integer>`. Find some Spring Data tutorial to know what's really going on in here, long story short the Spring Data is able to generate a lot of standard methods for you.

The method cityDTO.findById(id) returns `Optional<City>`, not `City`. To get the instance of City, just add '.get()' method, as it is in the example. It should work for you if city exists in the database. For proper work with `Optional` find some tutorial. It is a wrapper of an object that may or may not be present, detailed explanation is out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: I am new to this restful crud service.. I couldnt get much of what you meant:/

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. So do you think i go correctly, or i should change my CityController like this: `public @ResponseBody List<CityDTO> getCities() {
  List<CityDTO> cityDTOList = new ArrayList<CityDTO>();  
   List<City> cityList = cityService.findAll();
   for(City city:cityList) {
    CityDTO cityDTO = new CityDTO();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(city, cityDTO);
    cityDTO.setSelectable(true);
    cityDTOList.add(cityDTO);
   }
  }
  
  logger.trace("CityController: getAllCities ends");
  return cityDTOList;
 }`

Comment: btw even though I wrote this in CityService Sir, it still shows "red color" saying `this method is undefined in CityRepository`   `@Transactional
 public City getCity(int id) {
  return cityDTO.findById(id);
 }`

Comment: My bad, I have written the code out of my head. I didn't realize the metod findById returns Optional. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you a lot, i understand now. Btw do you have any tutorial or something to suggest me learn about spring-boot?

Comment: Spring and Spring Boot are huge frameworks, expect a few years until you understand what's going on there. Good starting point may be this https://spring.io/quickstart and generally these guides https://spring.io/guides

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to set up message converter manualy, google   MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and you'll know what to do.

Comment: ive to search about what it  means, but as i know i just should have a connection between entity, controller, service and repository. But i have missing parts...